# AWS S3: Share slice of zip via presigned url

Tags: amazon-s3

Can I create a [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html) in order to:

1. get a single file of zip
2. get a slice of a zip?

I mean, guess I've upload a zip file to AWS S3.
I'd like to share only one zip nested file.

I've took a look on S3 Select, but I don't quite figure out how to handle it or if it's posible to embed S3 Select behind a presinged URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not practically, no.  In theory, you could construct a presigned URL with a specific byte range request, but in practice, partial downloads from a zip file require at least three requests (one to find the extent of the header at the end of the file, one to read the header, and one to read the contents), and often require several.  You'd have to use a separate presigned URL for each request, and few clients offer such capabilities.  If you have complete control over the client, it might be possible, but even then, it's not trivial.